# Prove the continuity of a function in a normed space

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

> Let $(X,||·||)$ be a normed space over a field $\mathbb{K}$, where 
>   $$||x||=\max\{||x_1||,||x_2||\}$$
>   for any $x=(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{K}\times X$. Show that the mapping 
>   \begin{equation*}
> \begin{split}
> f : \mathbb{K}\times X & \to X \\
> (\alpha, x) & \mapsto \alpha x 
> \end{split}
> \end{equation*}
>   is continuous.

Firstly, I have shown that $||·||$ is in fact a well defined norm. Also, in this case $||·||=|·|$ for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{K}$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$, we choose $\delta>0$ such that if 
$$||(\alpha,x)-(\beta,y)||=\max\{|\alpha-\beta|,||x-y||\}<\delta$$
then 
$$||f(\alpha,x)-f(\beta,y)||=||\alpha x-\beta y||=||\alpha x-\alpha y +\alpha y-\beta y||\leq |\alpha|||x-y||+|\alpha-\beta|||y||\leq (|\alpha|+||y||)\max\{|\alpha-\beta|,||x-y||\}$$

However, I don't know how to conclude it, because of the term $|\alpha|+||y||$ which depends on the point I choose.

Comment: Observe that you are trying to prove **uniform continuity**, which does not hold.  Incidentally, $\mathbb{K}$ means $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I usually work with $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, but I'm trying to prove it in general

Comment: You have indeed proved continuity at $(\alpha, y)$ in your last but one inequality (assuming that $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: I don't understand you

Comment: Take $x \in X$ such that $\lVert x - y \rVert < \frac{\epsilon}{2 \lvert \alpha \rvert}$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{K}$ such that $\lvert \alpha - \beta \lvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2 \lVert y \rVert}$, with appropriate modifications when $\alpha = 0$ and/or $y = 0$.

Comment: Now I see. Thank you!

Comment: $\|x-y\|<\delta\implies |\alpha|+\|y\|<|\alpha|+\|x\|+\delta.$ So if $\delta$ is small enough that $(|\alpha| +\|x\|)\delta +\delta^2<\epsilon$  then $(|\alpha|+\|y\|)\max (|\alpha-\beta|,\|x-y\|)\le$ $ (|\alpha|+\|y\|)\delta \le$ $(|\alpha|+\|x\|+\delta)\delta<\epsilon$.... BTW if you type \|x\| for the norm of x instead of ||x||, it looks different and is easier to read.